# Couchbase Cluster creation issue

Tags: couchbase

I am have installed Couchbase on Docker using docker-compose file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  couchbase-server:
    container_name: project-couchbase
    image: couchbase/server
    ports:
      - 4369:4369
      - 8091:8091
      - 8092:8092
      - 8093:8093
      - 8094:8094
      - 11210:11210
      - 11211:11211
    volumes:
      - $HOME/couchbasesql:/var/lib/couchbase/data
```

Installation went fine but while creating cluster when i give my machine ip, I am getting following error

[image]

I have used all solution on google but still i am stuck here, it is taking 127.0.0.1 but not my machine ip which is needed for Couchbase clustering.
Can somebody help me on this ?

Comment: If this is your first cluster setup then you should be able to use loopback ip 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Nuwan,ok but when other node is joining my cluster how would he achieve this because couchbase asks for cluster ip there, which ip he should provide over there ?

Comment: Other nodes should be able to communicate with this node by its Docker assigned IP(172.31.195.103)

Comment: If i give docker assigned ip, i am getting Attention: Failed to reach erlang port mapper. Timeout connecting to "72.31.195.103" on port "4369".

Comment: You should try direct couchbase docker container without docker-composer.just for test weather you getting the same behavior.I tried and works as expected.
`docker run -d --name db -p 8091-8094:8091-8094 -p 11210:11210 couchbase` . more details here https://hub.docker.com/r/couchbase/server/